# spring form:select usage for multiselect

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to know how spring's multiple `form:select` works for following scenario:
I have a class `UniSection` has many students(`Student` class) and Students can selected zero or more selected course(`SelectedCourse` class) out of a list of courses(`Course` class)

```
public class UniSection{
 private List<Student> students;
}

public class Student{
  private List<SelectedCourse> selectedCourses;
}

public class SelectedCourses{
  private String courseName;
}
```

In my jsp page, for a UniSection, then first select a student and then select some courses.

My command object is uniSection, how can I do a multiSelect for a selectedCourse?

I would like to do something like this

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="???">
    <form:options items="courses" itemValue="???" itemLabel="???"/>
<form:select>
```

where courses is a list of all available courses. But what would come under path?
I dont think i can give `path=students.selectedCourses` as we need to assign course to particular student

I'm aware that i need a SelectedCoursePropertyEditor, but i don't know about the path expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show a multiple-select with courses I think you need something like that:

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="students[i].selectedCourses">
    <form:options items="${courses}" itemValue="courseName" itemLabel="courseName"/>
<form:select>
```

Where *i*, is a student from `UniSection`'s list, and *courses* is a list containing all courses. When you submit this data, property `Student.selectedCourses` will be filled with selected rows.